# Retriving current users information that stored in fire store under user id

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need some help. I had this code I am saving the user's information in the firestore database, so now I am trying to retrieve the data from it.
I had used this code to retrieve user names in other fragment and it works so I copy it to use it in this fragment. but it shows this error.

```
 private void checkuser() {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
        String name = user.getDisplayName();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
        boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();
        // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
        // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
        // FirebaseUser.getIdToken() instead.
        String uid = user.getUid();
        String userId = Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid().toString();

        DocumentReference ref=firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(userId);
        ref.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                assert value != null;

               // docView=value.getString("stage");
                textStage.setText(value.getString("name"));




            }
        });


    }


}
```

it shows me that

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.collection(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

> THIS CODE IS THE SAME AND WORKS IN THAT FRAGMENT

```
 private void init(){
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
    Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

    boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();

    // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
    // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
    // FirebaseUser.getIdToken() instead.
    String uid = user.getUid();

        String userId =mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();

        DocumentReference ref=firebase.collection("users").document(userId);
        ref.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                assert value != null;

                hello.setText(value.getString("name"));



                /**/
                if(isAdded()){
                    //Load image if the fragment is currently added to its activity.

                    if(value.getString("pic")==""){

                        Glide.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.applogoblue).into(userpicView);
                    }
                    else{


                        Glide.with(getContext()).load(value.getString("pic")).into(userpicView);
                    }
                }
                /**/







                /*if(value.getString("pic")==""){

                    Glide.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.applogoblue).into(userpicView);
                }
                else{


                    Glide.with(getContext()).load(value.getString("pic")).into(userpicView);
                }*/
            }
        });

}else{
    hello.setText("");
    Glide.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.applogoblue).into(userpicView);

}
```

Comment: Your firebaseFirestore object seems to be null at the point of calling the checkUser() function. Did you initialize it properly?

Comment: firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

Comment: I did it in onCreate

Comment: before calling checkUser()?

Comment: hmmmm, after :(